# Problem with saving chinese character into oracle using NHibernate

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate

I am trying to save chinese character into oracle DB using Nhibernate thru C# and the character saved always end up with some rubbish character.

I have done the following:

1. Hbm mapping for the field is
   declared as type AnsiString and
   column type as sql-type="nvarchar".
   Have also tried String and nvarchar2
   too.
2. Database column data type is
   NVARCHAR2.
3. Registry, environment
   variable and database charset
   NLS_LANG is set to UTF8.

I am able to read the chinese character input thru sql developer. But when I try to retrieve them (the character display correctly on screen) and attempt to save them back into the database without any changes, the data saved became "�����".

Anyone have any clue what have I miss out here?

Answer (score 1):

I would check what the data *really* is on the .NET side. Don't trust what's displayed on a console - look at the UTF-16 code points.

See my [debugging unicode article](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/debuggingunicode.html) for the general approach.

I seem to remember having some problems in Oracle before which were only fixed by setting the database encoding and then rebuilding the database - I couldn't apply it to an existing one. However, the details are in the dim and distant past...